# Is there a way to get a file stream to download to the browser in Blazor?

Tags: c#, browser, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying out a few things with Blazor and I'm still new to it. I'm trying to get a file stream to download to the browser. What's the best way to download a file from Blazor to browser?

I've tried using a method in my razor view that returns a stream but that didn't work.

```cs
//In my Blazor view
@code{
    private FileStream Download()
    {
        //get path + file name
        var file = @"c:\path\to\my\file\test.txt";
        var stream = new FileStream(test, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't give me anything, not even an error

Comment: Do I get it correctly that you want to download a file from the server to the client? Or you want to upload a file for processing, like an image upload?

Comment: My server(A) is sending out a request to another server(B) to get the file then give it to the browser, at least that's how I wanted it to work. I'm making a web request to another resource and I want it to trigger a browser download

Comment: I mean. . . why not just let users download direct from server (B)?

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to add a simple api controller endpoint using `endpoints.MapControllerRoute`. This will work only with server side blazor though.

Ex:

```
endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("mvc", "{controller}/{action}");
endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

Then add a controller. For example:

```
public class InvoiceController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("~/invoice/{sessionId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Invoice(string sessionId, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        return File(...);
    }
}
```

Usage in a .razor file:

```
async Task GetInvoice()
{
    ...
    Navigation.NavigateTo($"/invoice/{orderSessionId}", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer is technically correct, if you need to pass in a model -POST-, then NavigationManager won't work. In which case you, must likely end up using `HttpClient` component. If so wrap the response.Content -your stream- in a `DotNetStreamReference` instance - new DotNetStreamReference(response.Content). This will create a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream). Then create the blob with the content. Keep in mind `DotNetStreamReference` was recently introduced with .NET 6 RC1. As of now the most efficient way. Otherwise, you can use fetch API and create a blob from the response.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing it a different way, not needing `NavigationManager`. It was partially taken from the Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#download-from-a-stream). In my case I needed to render an Excel file (using EPPlus) but that is irrelevant. I just needed to return a `Stream` to get my result.

On my Blazor page or component when a button is clicked:

```
public async Task GenerateFile()
{
  var fileStream = ExcelExportService.GetExcelStream(exportModel);

  using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);

  await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", "Actual File Name.xlsx", streamRef);
}
```

The `GetExcelStream` is the following:

```
public static Stream GetExcelStream(ExportModel exportModel)
{
  var result = new MemoryStream();

  ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;
  var fileName = @$"Gets Overwritten";

  using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileName))
  {
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(exportModel.SomeUsefulName);
    var rowIndex = 1;

    foreach (var dataRow in exportModel.Rows)
    {
      ...
      // Add rows and cells to the worksheet
      ...
    }

    sheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

    package.SaveAs(result);
  }

  result.Position = 0; // This is required or no data is in result

  return result;
}
```

This `JavaScript` is in the link above, but adding it here as the only other thing I needed.

```
window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
  const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const anchorElement = document.createElement("a");

  anchorElement.href = url;
  anchorElement.download = fileName ?? "";
  anchorElement.click();
  anchorElement.remove();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```